# NAudio - Play an audio payload from a RTP packet

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I need to play a decoded audio payload from a RTP packet.
I am able to store the decoded payload into a memorystream 
but I don't know how to play it maybe using a library like NAudio.
I have a code like this:

```
MemoryStream payload = new MemoryStream();
bool RTPreceive = true;
while(RTPreceived)
```

..code to get the payload audio data from RTP packet

`payload.Write(packet,offset,lenght);`

Answer (score 0):

Put each decoded buffer of audio into a `BufferedWaveProvider` and play from that. You should make sure you've decoded to linear PCM first.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, supposing i have a byte[] payload how do i convert each byte[] array into pcm linear? thanks. i just started to learn naudio.

Comment: best starting point would be to look at the sourcecode for the NAudioDemo Network chat demo (part of the NAudio source repository)